# How to prevent php of loading a not requested page

Tags: php, shell, curl

I had a php page executing shellscripts very well untill I added a curl process, now, the page instead of loading the final result (print $output;) loads the page of the curl request, Is there a way to block this page of loading and have back the original behaviour?

this is my php code:

```
<?php
$thetext = $_POST['thetext'];

//unify orthography with NMT
//system("curl --data-urlencode 'contents=$thetext' http://www.chandia.net:8080/NMT");

//new code
// Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
   CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.chandia.net:8080/NMT',
   CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request',
   CURLOPT_POST => 1,
   CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
       'contents' => $thetext
   )
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);


//tokenize the textarea
system("cat ../NMT/nmt.txt | /opt/foma/linux64/flookup -i -x -w '' /srv/web/dungupeyem/tokenizer.fst > upfiles/thetext.tok"); 

//analyze the tokenized file
system("cat upfiles/thetext.tok | /opt/foma/linux64/flookup -s ' ==> ' -I f -I 1024k /srv/web/dungupeyem/dungupeyem.fst > upfiles/thetext.all");

//prepare text to output screen
system("grep '==> [^?+]' upfiles/thetext.all > upfiles/thetext.dpy");
system("sed -i 's/$/<br>/g' upfiles/thetext.dpy");

$output = file_get_contents("upfiles/thetext.dpy");
print $output;
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you using curl then?

Comment: because the unifying process is at another aplication running under cherrypy in port 8080, is there another way to do it?, I'm not an expert, if you can advice a better way I will follow you....

Comment: maybe try curling in php and not from shell

Comment: Here's an example: http://codular.com/curl-with-php of what Karl is talking about.

Comment: I tried with curl from php (http://hayageek.com/php-curl-post-get/) but it happened the same....

Comment: Ok, I have tried now with your suggestion, the curl requested page does not show anymore, but neither the one I would like to show, I've seen now that the procees does not get complited executing curl-php, while command line curl even though does not let me to show the result I want, let the process to finish

Comment: Ok, I have made the process to be completed but the output file does not show in screen, any ideas?

Comment: I edit the original question to add what I got now....

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, thanks to @mogosselin I've changed the code from shellscript to php function and finally it worked very well, the correct code is this one:

```
// Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.chandia.net:8080/NMT',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        'contents' => $thetext
    )
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);
```